# sequential blinking light animation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, animation

Imagine an old fashion pinball machine (or similar) with three light bulbs on either side of the machine's top scoreboard panel. The bulbs are numbered 1-6

Id like to be able to call a method that will flash the lights on for .5 sec then off again passing in an array of numbers as the sequence in which the lights should flash

I wrote the below which does work but seems very inefficient and needlessly verbose. Im thinking that using a timer would be better but Im not sure how to make that work with my "sequence" array

**Is there a better way to do this?**

```
- (IBAction)testLights:(id)sender {

    NSArray *sequence = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], [NSNumber numberWithInt:3], [NSNumber numberWithInt:4],[NSNumber numberWithInt:5],nil];
    [self setLights:sequence];
}

- (void)setLights:(NSArray *)sequence {

    UIImageView *light=[lgtArray objectAtIndex: [[sequence objectAtIndex:0]integerValue]];
    light.alpha = 0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                     animations:^{
                         light.alpha = 1;
                     }completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         //new annimation
                         light.alpha = 0;
                         UIImageView *light=[lgtArray objectAtIndex: [[sequence objectAtIndex:1]integerValue]];
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                                          animations:^{
                                              light.alpha = 1;
                                          }completion:^(BOOL finished){

                                              //new annimation
                                              light.alpha = 0;
                                              UIImageView *light=[lgtArray objectAtIndex: [[sequence objectAtIndex:2]integerValue]];
                                              [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                                                               animations:^{
                                                                   light.alpha = 1;
                                                               }completion:^(BOOL finished){

                                                                   //new annimation
                                                                   light.alpha = 0;
                                                                   UIImageView *light=[lgtArray objectAtIndex: [[sequence objectAtIndex:3]integerValue]];
                                                                   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                                                                                    animations:^{
                                                                                        light.alpha = 1;
                                                                                    }completion:^(BOOL finished){

                                                                                        //new annimation
                                                                                        light.alpha = 0;
                                                                                        UIImageView *light=[lgtArray objectAtIndex: [[sequence objectAtIndex:4]integerValue]];
                                                                                        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                                                                                                         animations:^{
                                                                                                             light.alpha = 1;
                                                                                                         }completion:^(BOOL finished){

                                                                                                             //new annimation
                                                                                                             light.alpha = 0;
                                                                                                             UIImageView *light=[lgtArray objectAtIndex: [[sequence objectAtIndex:5]integerValue]];
                                                                                                             [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                                                                                                                              animations:^{
                                                                                                                                  light.alpha = 1;
                                                                                                                              }completion:^(BOOL finished){

                                                                                                                                  light.alpha = 0;


                                                                                                                              }];


                                                                                                         }];


                                                                                    }];


                                                               }];



                                          }];


                     }];


}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284250/lights-animation-in-objective-c


I think this will help u

Comment: @user3536244 a little much to modify for my needs here but a very interesting approach thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by making the function recursive. I would suggest you pass the sequence object as an NSMutableArray.

```
- (void)setLights:(NSMutableArray *)sequence {

    if ([sequence count] > 0)
    {
        UIImageView *light=[lgtArray objectAtIndex: [[sequence objectAtIndex:0]integerValue]];
        [sequence removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        light.alpha = 0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                         animations:^{
                             light.alpha = 1;
                         }completion:^(BOOL finished){

                             [self setLights:sequence];
                         }];
    }
}
```

This function would have an added advantage of being able to handle a sequence of any number, instead of just 6.